# High Validation AUC - Low Test AUC

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, kaggle

I am working on a dataset called HR Attrition from kaggle (In class competition) it contains 1628 rows and 27 columns.
Most of the features are categorical in nature, I am using Random Forest and validating using Stratified K fold (10 folds) and my validation AUC is pretty high, around 0.98-99. On submitting I cant get an AUC of more than 0.85 which is a huge deviation. I have tried many things like PCA and feature selection but my validation is not trustworthy the submission score doesn`t improve.

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
# label encoding
lbl = LabelEncoder()
cat_feats = [f for f in train_data.columns if train_data[f].dtype == object]
for f in cat_feats:
train_data[f] = lbl.fit_transform(train_data[f])
test_data[f] = lbl.transform(test_data[f])

train_id = train_data.Id
train_data = train_data.drop(['Behaviour','Id'],axis = 1) # behaviour has 
# only 1 value

X = train_data.drop('Attrition',axis = 1)
y = train_data.Attrition

# Standard Scaling
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10,random_state=42,shuffle=True)

numeric = ['Age','MonthlyIncome','EmployeeNumber']
# target encoding
categorical = [f for f in X.columns if f not in numeric]
pre_pipe = make_column_transformer((TargetEncoder(),categorical), 
(StandardScaler(),numeric))
pipe_rf = make_pipeline(pre_pipe,RandomForestClassifier())

print('RF:',np.mean(cross_val_score(X=X,y=y,cv=skf,estimator=pipe_rf,scoring='accuracy')))
```

Using target encoding my validation gave me an average of 98% accuracy (the data is balanced so using accuracy the AUC is almost 1) but the submission score is at max 85%. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since your question is more about refining a model, and not about a coding issue specifically, your question seems more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I am just being naive here because generally cross validation score shouldn’t be that far from test score.

I just want to make sure we are talking the same metrics.

1. The cross-validation scores return accuracy
2. Maybe the competition is on AUC(Area under curve)

Accuracy can be 98% but AUC can still be only 85% 
If you want auc in cross validation predict update the last line with

print('RF:',np.mean(cross_val_score(X=X,y=y,cv=skf,estimator=pipe_rf,scoring= ‘roc_auc')))